# JsonString value to extract specific key

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Spec : JARS used Jackson for Json parsing /extraction in Java (JDK-15)

Statement : String val1 = ***"[  {"UnitId":"106","CategoryId":"403","ProductId":"103
","ProductName":"California Apples","ProductWeight":"250"} ]"***;

Question : I need to extract values of  "ProductName" from the Json Verified String.

Problem : I need to use **Jakson jar libraries Only** to parse & extract.
I have tried sample code using jackson libraries on stackoverflow...did not work.

If some body has sample code to try, please share.

with regard
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, if you don't want create object for that. You can do like this:

```
    private static JsonMapper JSON_MAPPER = new JsonMapper();

    public static String parseProductId(String rawJson) {
    try {
        JsonNode root = JSON_MAPPER.readTree(rawJson);
        return root.get(0).get("ProductId").asText();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Some information");
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this method gives flexibility if we need 1-2 fields.

Comment: This code works on raw Json with out using pojo or constraints.
Thanx for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson's [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to deserialize your JSON into a POJO.

The following code assumes that you have a `Product` POJO with fields corresponding to the ones in your JSON. Please make sure that the fields in your POJO are annotated using `@JsonProperty`:

```
public class Product {
    @JsonProperty("ProductName")
    private String productName;
    [...]
```

You can then map the JSON into an array:

```
Product[] products = objectMapper.readValue(val1, Product[].class);
```

If you prefer a list instead of an array, you can proceed as follows:

```
List<Product> products = objectMapper.readValue(val1, new TypeReference<List<Product>>(){});
```

Comment: Bro ... Sorry to say that i am not to use POJO to fetch the data, The String changes key:values some times ,  I need to fetch the value for the specified key in this sample code.